# MVC 5 EnumDropDownListFor implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I need to implement a dropdown box for the project. I used `enum` class to populate it, here is what i have

```
public class Media
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string tag { get; set; }  
    public TagsEnum TagsEnum { get; set; }
}
```

And enum class

```
public enum TagsEnum
    {
        Ecomomy,
        Latest,
        LocalNews,
        Interesting,
        WorldNews
    }
```

Create method

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,title,description,body,VideoLink, Source,tags")] Media media, HttpPostedFileBase file, int id = 0)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null)
                {
                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Images/")
                                                          + file.FileName);
                    media.ImagePath = file.FileName;
                }
                db.Medias.Add(media);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

And here is the problem, on my `Create` View i have dropdown list working fine, here is the code:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.tags, "News Category", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.TagsEnum)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tags)
        </div>
    </div>
```

But when i open a view page `MediaMain` were i have a list of media objects, even if i select different categories from dorpdown list i only have 1st one shown. Here is the code

```
foreach (var b in Model.media)
{
   ...
    <h5>Category: <a href=@Url.Action("Media", new { id = b.Id })>@Html.Raw(b.TagsEnum)</a></h5>
...
}
```

What do i misunderstand here, please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you are binding the properties of `Media` in you controller action result. The `Media` class has a property `public TagsEnum TagsEnum { get; set; }` which is bound to the drop down list but in the action result you are not binding it:

```
[Bind(Include = "Id,title,description,body,VideoLink, Source,tags")] Media media
```

This causes that the `TagsEnum` value will not be stored in the database so when you retrieve it in the list of media, it simply returns the first value of the enum. You are using a bunch of other fields like `VideoLink` or `tags` which are not properties of `Media` at all. Those are ignored, but if you want the `TagsEnum` to be assigned to the `media` variable, you must add it like this:

```
[Bind(Include = "Id,title,description,body,VideoLink, Source,tags, TagsEnum")] Media media
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm using those fields, i have just removed them to make class shorter, but yes u have a good point i will add this to Media class asap. Thanks again!